# Accessing dynamically generated DIV using document.getElementByID

Tags: javascript, html, forms, interactive

I am trying to access a dynamically generated DIV using document.getElementById but getting cannot set property innerHTML of null and that's pretty obvious.

Basically I am trying to build a type of interactive form just like https://www.typeform.com/

I want to create seperated DIV's for each question.

Here is what I have done so far:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Interactive Forms</title>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <center>
      <div id="playArea">
          <h3>Hello Stranger! Let's start</h3> <br/>
          <button id="start" onclick="Questions()">Let's start</button><span>or Hit Enter</span>
      </div>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
    var questions = [
    "Hey, what's you name?",
    "Can I know your E-mail ID please?",
    "Would you also like to subscribe to the newsletter?"
];
var html = "";
var i =0;
addEventListener("keydown", function(event){
  if(event.keyCode==13){
    Question();
  }
  if(event.code==39){
    nextQuestion();
  }
});
function Question(){
    html = questions[0]+"<br>"+"<input type='text' class='answer'><button onclick='nextQuestion()'>Ok</button><span>or Hit Right Arrow</span><br>";
    document.body.innerHTML = html;
    // document.getElementById("playArea").innerHTML = html;
    i++;
}
function nextQuestion(){
  if(i<questions.length){
    var html2 = "";
    newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    check="'answer"+i+"'";
    console.log("'answer"+i+"'");
    newDiv.setAttribute("id", "'answer"+i+"'");
    console.log(newDiv.id);
    html2 = questions[i]+"<br><input type='text' id='answer'><button onclick='nextQuestion()'>Ok</button><span>or Hit Right Arrow</span><br>";
    newDiv.innerHTML = html2;
    oQ = document.getElementById("otherQuestions");
    document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, oQ);
    i++;
}
  else{
  document.body.innerHTML = "Thank you for the response";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementById` gets an element, by its ID, **from the document**.

You haven't added the div to the document yet, so it can't be found.

---

That said you **already have the element**! There's no need to search for it, in the document or anywhere else.

```
newDiv.innerHTML = html2;
```

Comment: Yeah, the issue is resolved but the new questiosn are not popping up. Can you look into that too>

Comment: "You haven't added the div to the document yet"

Comment: How to do that? I am not getting it.

Comment: You managed to figure out `createElement`, the [MDN documentation for createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) has examples.

Comment: I managed to make it work but the code is working in an unusual manner. I am now using document.body.insertBefore. Editing the code once again for you to see. Please see the edit history.